# During checkout, when I click on review order, I would like to do some additional validation

Tags: 6, ubercart

When a user goes to checkout and clicks on "review", I would like to be able to hook into that process in order to do some custom validation.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a custom validation handler on the checkout form. This would mean the validation is done *before* you get to the review order screen. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubercart API provides a number of hook [points](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api) for this.  I would look at [hook_order](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_order) as a starting point for something like this and perhaps check a few of the other API options for Ubercart.

In the past, I have used hook_add_to_cart in order to review a product and determine if it should be allowed into the cart or not.  Not that this is what you are trying to do, but the API provides for a lot of flexibility.